# How do I import a .csv in R so it is subsettable?

Tags: r, read.csv

Note that I'm an almost absolute beginner!
I have a .csv file which I need to import into RStudio and then retrieve parts of columns to work with. I have done the following:

```
name_of_my_data_etc<-read.csv(<mydata>)
View(name_of_my_data_etc)
df[1:3,3]
```

and I get the error message: `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.
I've seen that this is a common problem, but can't understand how to remedy it and work with my .csv the way I need to.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide the name of the file as a string to read.csv, such as `my_data <- read.csv("data_file.csv")`.

Comment: Hi @rpolicastro, thanks for replying. I'm not quite sure what you mean; this is my exact code:example_name <- read.csv("~/Documents/example.csv")
>   View(example_name)
> df[1:3,2]
Error in df[1:3, 2] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a name of the object (`name_of_my_data_to_Global_environment`) to receive a result (in this case a data frame provided from the `read.csv()` function) from a function, using this `<-` .

```
name_of_my_data_to_Global_environment <- read.csv("name_of_my_data_etc.csv")

name_of_my_data_to_Global_environment[1:3,2]
#view 1,2,3 first rows of second column
```

**EDIT:**

This helped me comprehend the R language:

To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful:

1. Everything that exists is an object
2. Everything that happens is a function call

Comment: Hi @FrakTool, thanks so much, this helped me a lot.